# Remove a data frame row in R with a match over multiple Rows

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have data frame which looks like this:

```
content                                                ChatPosition
This is a start line                                   START
This is a middle line                                  MIDDLE
This is a middle line                                  MIDDLE
This is the last line                                  END
This is a start line with a subsequent middle or end   START
This is another start line without a middle or an end  START
This is a start line                                   START
This is a middle line                                  MIDDLE
This is the last line                                  END

content <- c("This is a start line" , "This is a middle line" , "This is a      middle line" ,"This is the last line" ,
         "This is a start line with a subsequent middle or end" , "This is     another start line without a middle or an end" ,
         "This is a start line" , "This is a middle line" , "This is the last line")
ChatPosition <- c("START" , "MIDDLE" , "MIDDLE" , "END" , "START" ,"START" , "START" ,"MIDDLE" , "END")
df <- data.frame(content, ChatPosition)
```

I'd like to delete the rows which contain a start but only if the next line doesn't contain a MIDDLE or END in the ChatPosition column.

```
content                                                ChatPosition
This is a start line                                   START
This is a middle line                                  MIDDLE
This is a middle line                                  MIDDLE
This is the last line                                  END
This is a start line                                   START
This is a middle line                                  MIDDLE
This is the last line                                  END

nrow(df)
jjj <- 0

for(jjj in 1:nrow(df))
{
  # Check of a match of two STARTS over over multiple lines.

 if (df$ChatPosition[jjj]=="START" && df$ChatPosition[jjj+1]=="START")

   {
    print(df$content[jjj])
    }

}
```

I was able to use the above code to print out the two lines i want to delete I am wondering what is the most elegant solution to remove these lines?

Also is a for with nested if the right approach here or is there a library which can do this type of thing much more easily?

Regards
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
df[!(as.character(df$ChatPosition) == "START" & 
   c(tail(as.character(df$ChatPosition), -1), "END") == "START"), ]

                     content ChatPosition
1       This is a start line        START
2      This is a middle line       MIDDLE
3 This is a      middle line       MIDDLE
4      This is the last line          END
7       This is a start line        START
8      This is a middle line       MIDDLE
9      This is the last line          END
```

The first argument in `[]` returns a logical vector that tells R what rows to keep. I use `tail(, -1)` to get the next observation of `df$ChatPosition` for comparison. Note that It is necessary to convert `df$ChatPosition` to character in the second line in order to concatenate "END" in the final position, since `df$ChatPosition` is a factor variable.

Comment: Thanks Imo is a really good and elegant (Very R) solution. I've tried it out and it gives the required result. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep`. You can compare this solution with your for loop on the real dataset for speed

```
start_indices = grep("START",ChatPosition)
end_indices = grep("END",ChatPosition)

match_indices = sapply(end_indices,function(x) tail(start_indices[(start_indices-x)<0],1) )
match_indices
# [1] 1 7
del_indices = setdiff(start_indices,match_indices)
del_indices
# [1] 5 6
DF_subset = DF[-del_indices,]
DF_subset
                     # content ChatPosition
# 1       This is a start line        START
# 2      This is a middle line       MIDDLE
# 3 This is a      middle line       MIDDLE
# 4      This is the last line          END
# 7       This is a start line        START
# 8      This is a middle line       MIDDLE
# 9      This is the last line          END
```

Comment: Thanks Osssan, this is a useful solution too using grep cheers

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !(ChatPosition == "START" & lead(ChatPosition) == "START"))
```

Which gives:

```
#                     content ChatPosition
#1       This is a start line        START
#2      This is a middle line       MIDDLE
#3 This is a      middle line       MIDDLE
#4      This is the last line          END
#5       This is a start line        START
#6      This is a middle line       MIDDLE
#7      This is the last line          END
```